# Xamarin - How to see the iOS Simulator app log

Tags: xamarin, ios-simulator

I recently upgraded some Firebase packages in my iOS Xamarin app, and now the thing refuses to work. The app opens (shows a splash screen) and immediately closes without producing an error.

While I want to fix the package problem, I have no clue where to start. I set a breakpoint on the App.xaml.cs constructor, but this never gets hit when I run the iOS version. So my next idea was to read the output like I do on Android.

I've been Googling around for a few hours, and everyone seems to say 'Go to Debug > Open System Log...', but this is absolutely rubbish! The system log seems to show everything except for my app running... (E.g. I run the app in the simulator, reload the system logs, and the freshest thing is from 10 minutes ago...)

I'm at my wits end here. Does anyone know a trick for viewing my app output in the simulator? Even just an exit code would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could view the logs in these locations:

**Mac** – `~/Library/Logs/Xamarin/Simulator.Server`

**Windows** – `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Logs\Xamarin.Simulator`